# How to convert DB2 set option to oracle?

Tags: oracle, db2

I try to covert DB2 SET option to Oracle, it's so hard. Couldn't found anyone had the same problem like I do. Really need some help.

```
SET OPTION 
ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE,
COMMIT = *NONE,
DECRESULT = (30, 30, 00),
DFTRDBCOL = *NONO,
DYNDFTCOL = *NO,
DYNUSRPRF = *USER,
SRTSEQ = *HEX
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option possible for what you are asking for. IBM DB2 is very different to Oracle, although both are RDBMS and support SQL and a lot of different features, the options of each one don't match.

If you want equivalences between your options in SET for DB2 against let say Oracle parameters, there are not. Most of the options are specific of the product itself and not transportable to the other database engine. For some, perhaps you can find a kind of equivalence, but you need to be careful about the meaning of the option itself in order to translate such meaning to another database engine.

Here a link to the IBM SHOW

[https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rdfi/9.6.0?topic=statements-set-option](http://IBM%20SHOW)

Example

**ALWCPYDTA**

Specifies whether a copy of the data can be used in a SELECT statement. This option will be ignored in REXX.

There is no translation to Oracle for this option, as there is neither copy of data as part of any select statement in Oracle, neither REXX. Those are exclusive of IBM DB2.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. I had a feeling that I might get this kind of answers , but it's good to know that. I think I'm getting a headache now.